# Hiding a Div for some of users

Tags: javascript, groups

I want to ask how could I Hide div for users wchich are isn't on Sharepoint one or two groups ? Could I use for it Javascript ? How could I read groups from Javascript. Is user exist on Sharepoint Group?

Answer (score 3):

Do it the other way around

1. Hide content by default
2. Add a Content Editor Editor WebPart
3. Add JavaScript to get the hidden content DOM element
4. Show the Content with Javascript (eg: `style.display='inline-block'`)
5. When all JavaScript works
6. Set the Target Audience on the CEWP to the groups that should see the content

Comment: But how? Could You giveme some links ?

Comment: **► Sounds like you are trying  to run before you can walk. Learn to do ►each individual step and then ONLY AFTER you master each individual step can you put them together.**

Answer (score 0):

You use the below java script to get current logged in user groups. you need give reference of `sp.js` and `sp.runtime.js`

```
<script src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () { ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(Checkuser, "sp.js"); })

function Checkuser() {
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var oWeb = clientContext.get_web();
var currentUser = oWeb.get_currentUser();
var allGroups = currentUser.get_groups();
clientContext.load(allGroups);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(OnSuccess, OnFailure);
}
function OnSuccess(sender, args)
{
    var grpsEnumerator = allGroups.getEnumerator();
    while(grpsEnumerator.moveNext())
    {

        var group = grpsEnumerator.get_current();

        var grpTitle = group.get_title();
        // You can write if condition to match for a particular group and hide the div

    }
}

function OnFailure(sender, args)
{
    console.log(args.get_message());
}
```

Comment: If I put this on script Editor it show me error when i try to write site.

Comment: I have modified the script please check you need to load `sp.js` and `sp.runtime.js`

Comment: Please look my answer